# Parse List[String] into HList

Tags: scala, shapeless

I would like to write `def parse[T <: HList](list: List[String]): Validation[T]`. `list` could be `List("fooid", "barid")`, and `T` `FooId :: BarId :: HNil`, and a typeclass `Parse[T]` which implements `String => Validation[FooId]`. How would I write said `parse`, which parses the list into `T`? I'm not sure how to summon the implicit typeclasses for each of the elements of `T`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can adapt the code from [`shapeless.ops.traversable.FromTraversable`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/ops/traversables.scala#L23-L53).

I'm not sure what your `Validation` type is, but I used it as an alias for `scalaz.ValidationNel[String, A]` below (mostly so I could use the `string` syntax to easily give me some `Parse` instances).

```
import scalaz.{Validation => _, _}, Scalaz._

type Validation[A] = ValidationNel[String, A]

trait Parse[T] {
  def apply(s: String): Validation[T]
}

object Parse {
  def fromScalazParse[E <: Exception, T](f: String => scalaz.Validation[E, T]) =
    new Parse[T] {
      def apply(s: String): Validation[T] =
        f(s).leftMap(_.getMessage).toValidationNel
    }

  implicit val booleanParse = fromScalazParse(_.parseBoolean)
  implicit val intParse     = fromScalazParse(_.parseInt)
  implicit val doubleParse  = fromScalazParse(_.parseDouble)
}
```

With the `Parser` type class sorted, we can now create a type class based on `FromTraversable` to parse a `List[String]` and give us a `Validation[A :: B :: HNil]` :

```
import shapeless._
import scala.collection.GenTraversable

trait FromTraversableParsed[Out <: HList] extends Serializable {
  def apply(l: GenTraversable[String]) : Validation[Out]
}

object FromTraversableParsed {
  def apply[Out <: HList](implicit from: FromTraversableParsed[Out]) = from

  implicit val hnilFromTraversableParsed = 
    new FromTraversableParsed[HNil] {
      def apply(l: GenTraversable[String]): Validation[HNil] =
        if(l.isEmpty) HNil.successNel[String]
        else "Traversable is not empty".failureNel[HNil]
    }

  implicit def hlistFromTraversableParsed[OutH, OutT <: HList](implicit 
    ftpT: FromTraversableParsed[OutT],
    parseH: Parse[OutH]
  ): FromTraversableParsed[OutH :: OutT] = 
    new FromTraversableParsed[OutH :: OutT] {
      def apply(l : GenTraversable[String]) : Validation[OutH :: OutT] =
        if(l.isEmpty) "Empty traversable".failureNel[OutH :: OutT]
        else (parseH(l.head) |@| ftpT(l.tail))(_ :: _)
    }
}
```

We can add some syntax to make using `FromTraversableParsed` a little bit easier :

```
implicit class ParseStringListOps(val strings: List[String]) extends AnyVal {
  def parse[L <: HList](implicit ftp: FromTraversableParsed[L]): Validation[L] =
    ftp(strings)
}
```

Now we can do :

```
List("1", "true", "3.0").parse[Int :: Boolean :: Double :: HNil]
// Validation[Int :: Boolean :: Double :: HNil] = Success(1 :: true :: 3.0 :: HNil)
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks pretty cool! In the gitter channel, https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/ops/hlists.scala#L2815 has been mentioned, would it be possible to use that and skip writing your own TC?

Comment: I think `LiftAll` can give us `Parse[Int] :: Parse[Boolean] :: Parse[Double] :: HNil`, but I'm not sure how we can use this to parse a `List[String]` ?

Comment: I figured something along the lines of `List[String] => String :: String :: String :: HNil`, zip that with the `HList` from `LiftAll`, then traverse over it with validation.

Comment: That should be possible, but then you would also need `shapeless-contrib`, and I would say that it is probably more complicated than writing the type class above.

Comment: @Reactormonk [Here](https://gist.github.com/peterneyens/ab820dcaac1cb3cf6b83d00df9bbed85) is a partial solution using the method you described.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, you're correct, a custom TC is a better approach in this case.